# JQuery: Reapply document.ready after "show more" appended HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which displays a list of search results. The titles are truncated to 1 line using the script trunk8. This is activated in the header like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.resulttitle').trunk8({
      lines: 1
    });
});
```

which ensures that any long titles are only one line and end with `...`

At the bottom of the page is a "show more" button which pulls in more results by loading another page in the background which returns an HTML result of the additional results that are then appended to a div.

My problem is that the new results which are appended to the previous results are not truncated because they were not present on the document load.

How do I get the trunk8 function to apply to these appended results?

Comment: You're going to need to tell us more about how the show more button works.  How does it pull in the extra page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are doing an AJAX call to get the additional results.
Then you can run the "trunk8" script after you successfully get the items and add them to the div.

```
$.get( your ajax call parameters ).done(function(data){
    //you add the items to the div here
    $('.resulttitle').trunk8({
    lines: 1
    });
});
```